# Python regex for string up to character or end of line

Tags: python, regex

I want a regex that stops at a certain character or end of the line. I currently have:

```
x = re.findall(r'Food: (.*)\|', text)
```

which selects anything between "Food:" and "|". For adding end of the line, I tried:

```
x = re.findall(r'Food: (.*)\||$', text)
```

but this would return empty if the text was 'Food: is great'. How do I make this regex stop at "|" or end of line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use negation based regex `[^|]*` which means anything but `pipe`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'Food: ([^|]*)', 'Food: is great|foo')
['is great']
>>> re.findall(r'Food: ([^|]*)', 'Food: is great')
['is great']
```

Comment: `print re.findall(r'Food: (.*)(?:\||$)', 'Food: is great|foo')` prints `['is great|foo']`

Comment: This works for end of line, but fails on stopping before "|". For example, if I have: "Food: is great | hello", it returns "is great | hello", rather than "is great"

Answer (score 0):

A simpler alternative solution:

```
def text_selector(string)
    remove_pipe = string.split('|')[0]
    remove_food_prefix = remove_pipe.split(':')[1].strip()
    return remove_food_prefix
```